# hibernate envers default schema does not work

Tags: hibernate, spring-data, hibernate-envers

i have one project with maven, and i used spring data and JPA(hibernate) in it. and it configured by XML.
default schema of envers has changed. but it doesnt works. when i seeing the DDL output, it says :

> ERROR org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate - HHH000388:
>   Unsuccessful: alter table VETERANS_AUD.USERPROFILE_ROLE_AUD add
>   constraint FK_nbpfx0rjc9hqiaiv4vofp82kc foreign key (REV) references
>   VETERANS_AUD.AuditedRevisionEntity 12:54:37.322
>   [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate
>   - ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

the problem is:the tables has not created in defined schema, but constraints wants to create in the defined schema.
I used @AuditTable but the problem has exists. the audition tables doesn't create in defined schema.

part of my pom is :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-envers</artifactId>
        <version>0.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
```

this is my configuration :

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" p:persistenceXmlLocation="classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml" p:dataSource-ref="dataSource">
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"  p:databasePlatform="${hibernate.dialect}" p:showSql="${hibernate.show_sql}" p:generateDdl="${hibernate.generate_ddl}" />
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="org.hibernate.envers.default_schema">${hibernate.envers_schema}</prop>
                <prop key="spring.jpa.properties.org.hibernate.envers.default_schema">${hibernate.envers_schema}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.default_schema">${hibernate.default_schema}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="org.hibernate.envers.revision_on_collection_change">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy">org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultComponentSafeNamingStrategy</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>com.dpj.veterans.model.domain</value>
                <value>com.juice.applejuice.audition</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

how can i resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a custom Revision info table you must specify the schema as part of the @Table annotation, ie.

```
@Table(name = "rev", schema = "schema")
```